# Creating a new Visual Studio solution from the command line

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, devenv

Is there a way I can use devenv to create a new Visual Studio solution from a multi-project template that I made. There are lots of resources on building with the command line, but I can't seem to find anything on creating a new solution. I want to be able to open a new solution from the template from a code generator that I made, so that I can then generate code and add it to the "skeleton".

Thanks

Comment: Why do it from the command-line, per se? Use Automation.

Comment: Not directly an answer but CMake does this, perhaps you can look at its code.

Comment: There's no such option.  Solution and project files are pretty simple XML files.  Just write the xml.

Comment: @JohnSaunders the last time I checked, shell scripting was the most powerful and flexible form of automation. Classic Microsoft, limiting people to simplistic, predefined workflows.

Comment: @nick when I said "Automation" i meant the Visual Studio API.

Comment: Well now I sound like an idiot and jerk. 
Consider my foot in my mouth.

Comment: Hi Lee, did you ever find a good solution to this?  besides just writing the xml?

Comment: @HansPassant any known updates to this?

Comment: https://github.com/themotleyfool/SlimJim looks promising